# EF4 Unable to load one or more of the requested types on test server

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, installation

I developed an ASP.NET v4 application using Entity Framework 4. I'm deploying it to the test server (Windows 2008 R2 with .NET Framework 4 installed).

The application throws this error:

> [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable
>   to load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule
>   module) +0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
>   +144    System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
>   +45    System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
>   +34    System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean
>   loadReferencedAssemblies,
>   ObjectItemLoadingSessionData
>   loadingData) +130
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean
>   loadReferencedAssemblies,
>   KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies,
>   EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection,
>   Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object&
>   loaderCookie, Dictionary`2&
>   typesInLoading, List`1& errors) +248
>
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection
>   objectItemCollection, Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean
>   loadReferencedAssemblies,
>   EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection,
>   Action`1 logLoadMessage) +580
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type
>   type, EdmItemCollection
>   edmItemCollection) +121
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type
>   type, Assembly callingAssembly) +178
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetTypeUsage(Type
>   entityCLRType) +49
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet(String
>   entitySetName) +163
>   PageManager.FetchDefaultPage()
>   +114

When I look on my development PC I see this directory with assemblies:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

But on the server the whole .NETFramework directory is missing, there is just a v3.0 and v3.5 directory. I assume the server is using the assembly from one of these directories which are version 3.5.0.0 and not 4.0.0.0 (what my app is referencing).

What do I need to install? .NET 4 is installed on the server i'm 100% sure.

Comment: If there's no v4.0.x.x folder .net is **not** installed. For 100% sure.

Comment: Well, I have other .NET 4 apps running which do not require EF4. And the are definately using .NET 4... also re-run the .NET4 install and did a repair.

Comment: Also C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was nothing to do with .NET 4. I caught the ReflectionTypeLoadException and looped the LoaderExceptions. References to Microsoft.SyncronisationFramework were missing.

Perhaps a direct message in the exception with a list of missing references would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your question is answered here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx